# Xpages - blank fields overwritten with value saved in document if validation fails

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Im making an Xpages application which needs to have server-side validation.

In my form, when a field is cleared and the form submitted - if there is another field which causes the validation to fail - it will be repopulated with the last successfully saved value in the document.

This is not what should happen. The field should stay blank until the page is either refreshed, or the user enters another value.

Does anyone have any idea about what is causing this to happen?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. As far as I can tell, it was simply due to the way the default converter included with xpages handles the object and/or string. Writing a java custom converter sorted everything out.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your execId and refreshId.

For what happens during partial refresh, read these blog posts, particularly part three http://www.intec.co.uk/tag/partial-refresh/.

If validation (or conversion) fails server-side, the server-side map of the XPage is not updated because the data is not deemed complete enough for server-side processing.

So the partial refresh skips to Render Response, which posts back what HTML should be displayed to the page. That includes values in fields - you're replacing HTML, so it has to.

If you're save button is refreshing the form area, you'll be replacing the HTML there, so overwriting the values entered by the user with the last valid values.

The recommended approach will depend on your page architecture and what you're saving. One is to move validation to the save() function, by which time the values will have been updated in the DominoDocument (the front-end wrapper for the Document on the server). Another is to only refresh the validation area and, if validation was successful, call `context.reloadPage()` or `context.redirectToPage()` to effectively skip the partial refresh.

Comment: thanks for the reply Paul. Currently my save is a simple action (save data sources). I have repeated panels with a data source bound to each.  My confusion stems from the fact that if i have a number of fields flagged as invalid, then i change ONE to a valid number, that new number will still be retained in the input when the validation fails next. However, if i change ONE field to null, that is overwritten. From what you are saying, this is considered standard? Why does it only occur when the field is blank and how can I get around it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your recommendation. How can I move validation to the save() function? With a button I thought I can either have it on, or I can have it off (via the process without validators checkbox).

Comment: I did some more experimenting and determined that a blank field is repopulated from the document if the field has a converter on it (I was using a number converter). Alternatively, if the field is for a string, the blank value is not repopulated. Any ideas?

Comment: It's probably going to stem from when the converter is triggered, what is stored in the component and what is in the HTML passed to the browser. It would probably needs some debugging to get an understanding. You won't be able to use a simple action to do the validation, you will need SSJS (or Java if you're business logic is in Java).